# Continuous, strictly monotonic and odd functions

Tags: polynomials, continuity, monotone-functions, even-and-odd-functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, strictly monotonic and odd.

Is $f$ necessarily a polynomial function?

Comment: $2x+\sin(x)$ is not a polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $f(x)=\sinh(x)$? Or $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=e^{x}-1$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ for $x \leq 0$ has these properties.